# [Python]Detect message topic by keyword

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe like this:

first one with keywords and topic names

```
Topic        Keyword
Math        ['plus','subtract','multiply','devide']
IT          ['computer','cpu', 'mainboard','monitor']
Chemistry   ['Water','Acid','Calcium','Soldium']
Biology     ['plant','DNA','gerne','evolution','chromosomes']
```

second one with message like this

```
id      message
0       one plus one is two
1       buy me a computer
2       put calcium in acid
3       23 pairs of chromosomes
```

How can I detect each message topic in the second dataframe by keywork in the first dataframe?
I want the final result to look like this:

```
message                   topic
one plus one is two       math
buy me a computer         IT
put calcium in acid       Chemistry
23 pairs of chromosomes   Biology
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your required output:

I have created two dataframes one for `keywords` and another for `message`

The below code will give you desired output:

```
import pandas as pd

# First dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'message': ['one plus one is two', 'buy me a computer', 'put calcium in acid', '23 pairs of chromosomes']})

# Second dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Topic': ['Math', 'IT', 'Chemistry', 'Biology'],
                    'Keyword': [['plus', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'devide'], 
                                ['computer', 'cpu', 'mainboard', 'monitor'], 
                                ['Water', 'Acid', 'Calcium', 'Sodium'], 
                                ['plant', 'DNA', 'gerne', 'evolution', 'chromosomes']]})

# Adding a new column 'id' to df1
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Merging the dataframes using 'id'
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

# Extracting 'Keyword' column and create a new column 'topic'
merged_df['topic'] = merged_df['Keyword'].apply(lambda x: x[0])

# Dropping the 'Keyword' and 'topic' columns
merged_df.drop(['Keyword', 'topic'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Printing the final dataframe
print(merged_df)
```

Hope it will helpful to you

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to [**`merge()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two dataframes and then drop the these two columns `['id', 'Keyword']`
**Note:** `df1` in the code snippet represents your dataframe with the message column and `df2` represents the dataframe with the keyword column.

```py
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
new_df.drop(['id', 'Keyword'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
                   message      Topic
0      one plus one is two       Math
1        buy me a computer         IT
2      put calcium in acid  Chemistry
3  23 pairs of chromosomes    Biology
```